# How to get group id from custom url

Tags: organic-groups, uri

I have some more custom url with og group id like

1. www.example.com/students/6593
2. www.example.com/results/6953
3. www.example.com/book-listing/5367/6953

   here 6953 is a group id.

these are the sample link. my questions is how to get the group id from url? And i can't use arg(). because i have more no of url and group id position also varied.

There is any robust solutions for this.

Comment: Is it going to be always the last part of the URL?

Comment: @Djouuuuh , Not, it would be in any place.

Comment: Is your group a custom content-type or taxonomy?

Comment: @Djouuuuh , Its a custom content type make it as group by the og module.

Comment: Where do you want to recover the group id? On a node page? On a View? What is the context?

Comment: @Djouuuuh, It is a view page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18760/discussion-between-leopathu-and-djouuuuh).

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code in hook_preprocess_page() to solve this issue.

```
$url = current_path();
  $arguments = explode('/', $url);
  foreach ($arguments as $value) {
    if (is_numeric($value)) {
      $node = node_load($value);
      if (og_is_group('node', $node)) {
        drupal_set_message('group id :' . $node->nid);
      }
    }
  }
```

From now, i can set to group member only could see this page.